# Tables stored in clipboard

Tags: excel, vba, clipboard

I receive a table via email. 
I then copy the table and want to use VBA to populate the data in a list box using MS Excel. 
However, when I use the method GetText, I cannot find a column delimiter. I would have expected Tab as this is what I see when I paste the table into notepad++. 
Instead I get 2 or 3 spaces between columns. 
Any idea how I can separate the columns in the clipboard?

Comment: Difficult to answer without any example data.  You could try splitting each line on the double space instead of on tab.  That should work as long as the table data doesn't contain double spaces

Comment: Maybe you could first paste it in a sheet and populate your Listbox from there?

Comment: @EvR yes, that would be my workaround but I hoped that there would be a more elegant solution.

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes, however (and I haven’t found a rule yet) the column delimiter could be one, two or three spaces depending of the data in the column. Just saw this behavior towards the end of my columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First split on vbNewline and **then** per line on vbTab to create an array in memory and finally use Index to retrieve a column. (but first putting it in a listbox (memory) and then getting a column out looks easier to me)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim DataObj As MsForms.DataObject
Set DataObj = New MsForms.DataObject
Dim mytxt As String, arr() As String
Dim ff() As String, qq() As String, i As Integer, j As Long

DataObj.GetFromClipboard
    mytxt = DataObj.GetText(1)
    arr() = Split(mytxt, vbNewLine)
        ReDim ff(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To UBound(Split(arr(0), vbTab)) + 1)
            For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
                qq = Split(arr(i - 1), vbTab)
                    For j = 1 To UBound(qq) + 1
                        ff(i, j) = qq(j - 1)
                    Next j
            Next

ListBox2.List = Application.Index(ff, 0, 2) '2nd column

End Sub
```

Comment: Works like a Charme! Thanks so much!